# Undefined reference: Generic vector in C with Macro

Tags: c, generics, vector

I tried some stuff there, but I'm a noob at this so if someone can explain why I have a multiple definition error? And why I have undeclared function by the way?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I tried to reduce the code, but I don't think I can further reduce it, so it looks really similar to the version prior to this edit. Sorry.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried something (separate `struct` and function declaration of vector) but I still have one last error :s

vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H_
# define VECTOR_H_

# include   <stdlib.h>

# define    DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE 2

typedef unsigned char   t_byte;
typedef struct s_vector t_vector;

struct      s_vector
{
  size_t    stype;
  size_t    size;
  size_t    capacity;
  void      *data;
};

t_vector    *new_vector(size_t);
void        delete_vector(t_vector *);

# define VECTOR_GENERATE_STRUCT_TYPE(TYPE) VECTOR_GENERATE_NAME(TYPE, TYPE)
# define VECTOR_GENERATE_STRUCT_NAME(TYPE, NAME)                     \
  typedef struct    s_vector_##NAME{                                 \
    size_t      size;                                                \
    size_t      capacity;                                            \
    TYPE        *data;                                               \
  }         t_vector_##NAME;                                         \
                                                                     \
  t_vector_##NAME   *vector_##NAME_new();                            \
  void          vector_##NAME_delete(t_vector_##NAME *);             \
  int           vector_##NAME_init(t_vector_##NAME *this);           \


# define VECTOR_GENERATE_FUNC_TYPE(TYPE)    VECTOR_GENERATE_FUNC_NAME(TYPE, NAME)
# define VECTOR_GENERATE_FUNC_NAME(TYPE, NAME)                      \
  t_vector_##NAME   *vector_##NAME_new()                            \
  {                                                                 \
    return ((t_vector_##NAME *)new_vector(sizeof(TYPE)));           \
  }                                                                 \
                                                                    \
  void          vector_##NAME_delete(t_vector_##NAME *this)         \
  {                                                                 \
    delete_vector((t_vector *)this);                                \
  }                                                                 \
    int         vector_##NAME_init(t_vector_##NAME *this)           \
  {                                                                 \
    return (vector_init((t_vector *)this, sizeof(TYPE)));           \
  }                                                                 \

VECTOR_GENERATE_STRUCT_NAME(t_byte, byte)
#endif
```

vector.c:

```
#include    "vector.h"

VECTOR_GENERATE_FUNC_NAME(t_byte, byte)
int     vector_init(t_vector *vector)
{
  vector->size = 0;
  vector->capacity = DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE;
  if ((vector->data = malloc(DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE)) == NULL)
    return (-1);
  umemset(vector->data, 0, DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE);
  return (0);
}

t_vector    *new_vector(size_t stype)
{
  t_vector  *vector;

  vector = (t_vector *)malloc(sizeof(t_vector));
  if (vector != NULL)
    {
      vector->size = 0;
      vector->capacity = DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE;
      if ((vector->data = malloc(DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE)) == NULL)
    {
      free(vector);
      return (NULL);
    }
      umemset(vector->data, 0, DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE);
    }
  return (vector);
}

void        delete_vector(t_vector *this)
{
  if (this->data != NULL)
    free(this->data);
  free(this);
}

int     vector_extend(t_vector *this,
                  size_t type)
{
  void      *new;
  unsigned int  i;

  i = 0;
  this->capacity = this->size * type;
  --this->capacity;
  while (i < type)
    {
      this->capacity |= this->capacity << i;
      i *= 2;
    }
  ++this->capacity;
  new = malloc(this->capacity * 2);
  if (new == NULL)
    return (-1);
  this->capacity *= 2;
  umemcpy(this->data, new, this->size * type);
  return (0);
}

void        vector_clear(t_vector *this)
{
  free(this->data);
  this->size = 0;
  this->capacity = 0;
  this->data = NULL;
}
```

buffer.h:

```
#ifndef BUFFER_H_
# define BUFFER_H_

# include   <stdlib.h>
# include   <unistd.h>
# include   "vector.h"

typedef unsigned char   t_byte;

# define    IN  0
# define    OUT 1

VECTOR_GENERATE_NAME(t_byte, byte)

typedef struct s_buffer t_buffer;

struct      s_buffer
{
  int       fd[2];
  unsigned int  cursor;
  t_vector_byte *contents;
};

t_buffer    *new_buffer(int, int);
void        delete_buffer(t_buffer *);
#endif
```

buffer_new.c :

```
#include    "buff.h"

t_buffer    *new_buffer(int in,
                int out)
{
  t_buffer  *buffer;

  buffer = (t_buffer *)malloc(sizeof(t_buffer));
  if (buffer != NULL)
    {
      buffer->fd[IN] = in;
      buffer->fd[OUT] = out;
      buffer->cursor = 0;
      vector_byte_init(buffer->contents);
    }
  return (buffer);
}
```

buffer_delete.c:

```
#include    "buff.h"

void        delete_buffer(t_buffer *buffer)
{
  if (buffer != NULL)
    {
      free(buffer);
    }
}
```

About errors:

```
 vector.c: In function ‘vector_init’:
vector.c:11:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘umemset’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   umemset(vector->data, 0, DEFAULT_VECTOR_SIZE);
   ^
vector.c: In function ‘vector_extend’:
vector.c:60:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘umemcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   umemcpy(this->data, new, this->size * type);
   ^
buff_new.c: In function ‘new_buffer’:
buff_new.c:14:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘vector_byte_init’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       vector_byte_init(buffer->contents);
       ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccbJdFjO.o: In function `vector_init':
vector.c:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `umemset'
/tmp/ccbJdFjO.o: In function `new_vector':
vector.c:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference to `umemset'
/tmp/ccbJdFjO.o: In function `vector_extend':
vector.c:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `umemcpy'
/tmp/ccdymmO4.o: In function `new_buffer':
buff_new.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `vector_byte_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

buffer.h is the only file which include vector.h, but it's included in some other files.

I think that's all; I compile with GCC 4.9.
So, if someone has any clue for me, it would be cool!

Comment: Please construct a minimal test-case.

Comment: If i make only one file it's working, but i can't try something with just two maybe.
Edit : I just tried to compile only file above (so 4 .c and 2 .h) which is the minimal set for this to compile. And errors are exactly the same

Comment: Stopp just adding stuff; Noone will read that for you. Just create a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It won't be really minimal, but i can try something

Comment: You might first think about the implications of my answer.

Comment: It seems that gcc use a hack like this for vector in his C version.
I'll try to find something there

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "hack"? I'd not suspect gcc for a "hack" here.

Comment: I heard this to speak of tricks i thinks, but if you said that i think that i'm wrong ^^ sorry for that. So i just wanted to say, that somebody on stack overflow said that gcc use "macro template" to implement a vector. But i didn't find the right code

Answer (score 0):

You do have object *definitions* in a header file. This is included into every implementation file (`.c`) as if the same text had been pasted. This results every implementation file to define the objects created => multiple definitions.

Just have object *declarations* in the header (each preceeded by `extern` qualifier to signal *declaration*-only) and put the definitions into a single implementation file (most likely the same basename as for the header file). Like that to your project.

**Edit:**

According to the names in the error report, the problem seems to be due to buffer.h which is not posted, but as it includes vector.h, That would result in exactly what I described above. You should read the error messages carefully and try to understand them.

**Edit 2:**

You should check if the macro really does expand the way you expect. For such large macros it is better to start with a small version and elaborate step-wise. Such constructs tend to create something different than expected and might get along unnoticed.

Comment: My bad, i forget to copy paste buffer.h :s sorry and thanks to answer.
So you mean, even in meta programming i can't use VECTOR_GENERATE_TYPE(TYPE) in a header file?
But if so, i will define the vector type in every source file which need it?

Comment: Do not do that! your question already contains too much pasted stuff. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: C has no **meta-programming**. The preprocessor just does text replacement (and removes comments).

Comment: Yes i know that, it's just to make things generics without use byte as basic type.

Comment: Hmm.. had a closer look at your code now. Well, you really should not have a space between `#` and the cpp-instruction; this confuses the syntax-highlighter, showing this line as a comment. However, that macro looks strange anyways.

Comment: So, if you know that C does not have meta-programming, why are you refereing to it then?

Comment: Yes you're right oO i don't know why, maybe it's because it's the first time i tried this and i infortunatly connected it to metaprogramming.. And sorry about the code "style" it's a rule of my school ^^"

Comment: So much for "learning for life"! You'll have a hard time if you ever start a job with this style. However, I bet this extremely long macro is not part of the styleguide. You might have a look at boost; this uses a diffferent (and more accepted) approach for such hacks.

Comment: I know that is style is ugly, it's just a code from a school project so i forget to remove that.
Boost use macro llike this? it's not cpp? I'll see it this summer, thanks

Comment: About my code, do you know why guard include didn't block multiple definition? That seems pretty weird for me

Comment: Please understand this is not tutorial site. Just have a look at this. Ok, in brief: boost does use the cpp (what else could also be used in C?), but it uses multiple includes instead of macros. This requires-of course to taylor each #include of the same file to a specific problem. That way, it implements cpp-counters for instance, but also more complex stuff.

Comment: Oh, and check your other questions.